# resizing image in codeigniter php not working correctly

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, image-resizing

I am trying to resize multiple images using codeigniter, my file upload code in controller looks like below:

```
$this->load->library('upload');
$image = array();
$ImageCount = count($_FILES['pimage']['name']);
for($i = 0; $i < $ImageCount; $i++){
    $_FILES['file']['name']       = $_FILES['pimage']['name'][$i];
    $_FILES['file']['type']       = $_FILES['pimage']['type'][$i];
    $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']   = $_FILES['pimage']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $_FILES['file']['error']      = $_FILES['pimage']['error'][$i];
    $_FILES['file']['size']       = $_FILES['pimage']['size'][$i];

    // File upload configuration
    $uploadPath = './uploads/products/';
    $config['upload_path'] = $uploadPath;
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';

    // Load and initialize upload library
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);

    // Upload file to server
    if($this->upload->do_upload('file')){
        // Uploaded file data
        $imageData = $this->upload->data();
        $uploadImgData[] = $imageData['file_name'];
        $this->resizeImage($imageData['file_name']);
    }
}
                 
                 
                 
public function resizeImage($filename)
{
    $source_path = './uploads/products/' . $filename;
    $target_path = './uploads/products/';
    $config_manip = array(
          'image_library' => 'gd2',
          'source_image' => $source_path,
          'new_image' => $target_path,
          'maintain_ratio' => TRUE,
          'width' => 500,
    );
   
    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config_manip);
    if (!$this->image_lib->resize()) {
        echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
    }
   
    $this->image_lib->clear();
}
```

Here I have two issues, first one is only the first image is getting resized, multiple images are not. Second thing is: if portrait image is uploaded its turned into landscape after conversion. Can anyone please tell me what is wrong in here, thanks in advance

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: load your libraries before the loops and only once, initialize when calling. Concerning *if portrait image is uploaded its turned into landscape after conversion*: did you check the image itself? the output in the img tag might appear landscape, but the image continues portrait?

Comment: @Vickel can u please show as an answer. and the portrait landscape issue is when images taken from mobile are uploaded, portrait turning into landscape both in folder and in display